# Flutter CupertinoTimerPicker does not fit to parent width or height

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried container with width and height using double.infinity, SizedBox and SizeBox.expand. the widget does not fit into the parent width and height. anyone can help?

[image]

```
class _SetTimerButtonState extends State<SetTimerButton> {
  List<String> _timerPicker = ["0", "1", "2", "3"];
  Duration initialtimer = new Duration();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) => FlatButton(
        color: Colors.white,
        textColor: Colors.grey,
        disabledColor: Colors.grey,
        disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        // splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            ),
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext builder) {
              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3,
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  // height: double.infinity,
                  // width: double.infinity,
                  child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                    mode: CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hms,
                    minuteInterval: 1,
                    secondInterval: 1,
                    initialTimerDuration: initialtimer,
                    onTimerDurationChanged: (Duration changedtimer) {
                      setState(() {
                        initialtimer = changedtimer;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                )
              );
            }
          );
        },
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                "No Timer",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTimerPicker-class.html) the picker has a fixed size:

> The picker has a fixed size of 320 x 216, in logical pixels, with the
>   exception of CupertinoTimerPickerMode.hms, which is 330 x 216. If the
>   parent widget provides more space than it needs, the picker will
>   position itself according to its alignment property.